# Exponentially grow the number of processes in C++

Tags: c++, ipc, message-passing

I am writing an application the sends messages between processes in C/C++ and this is the code I have so far:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>


#define MSGSZ 128

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

/*
 * Declare the message structure.
 */

typedef struct msgbufer {
    long    mtype;
    char    mtext[MSGSZ];
} message_buf;

int main()
{
    int msqid;
    int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
    key_t key;
    message_buf sbuf;
    size_t buf_length;

    /*
     * Get the message queue id for the
     * "name" 1234, which was created by
     * the server.
     */
    key = 1234;

    (void) fprintf(stderr, "\nmsgget: Calling msgget(%i,\
%#o)\n",
                   key, msgflg);

    if ((msqid = msgget(key, msgflg )) < 0) {
        perror("msgget");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        (void) fprintf(stderr,"msgget: msgget succeeded: msqid = %d\n", msqid);


    /*
     * We'll send message type 1
     */

    sbuf.mtype = 1;


    (void) strcpy(sbuf.mtext, "Hello other process 2.");

    buf_length = strlen(sbuf.mtext) + 1 ;

    /*
     * Send a message.
     */

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    int err = msgsnd(msqid, &sbuf, buf_length, IPC_NOWAIT);
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    if (err < 0) {
        printf ("%d, %li, %s, %lu\n", msqid, sbuf.mtype, sbuf.mtext, buf_length);
        perror("msgsnd");
        exit(1);
    }

    else
        printf("Message: \"%s\" Sent\n", sbuf.mtext);

    auto duration = duration_cast<nanoseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();

    cout << "Execution time 2: " << duration << endl;

    pid_t recProcess = fork();

    if(recProcess == 0){

        int msqid;
        key_t key;
        message_buf  rbuf;

        /*
         * Get the message queue id for the
         * "name" 1234, which was created by
         * the server.
         */
        key = 1234;

        if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0666)) < 0) {
            perror("msgget");
            exit(1);
        }


        /*
         * Receive an answer of message type 1.
         */
        if (msgrcv(msqid, &rbuf, MSGSZ, 1, 0) < 0) {
            perror("msgrcv");
            exit(1);
        }

        /*
         * Print the answer.
         */
        printf("Message recieved: %s\n", rbuf.mtext);

    }

    exit(0);
}
```

In this case I have only two processes one sending a message and the other one receiving it.
I need to grow the number of the processes that send and receive messages by the power of two (e.g. 2, 4, 8, 16..) processes at the same time in memory sending messages to one another (e.g. 1 process send a message and the other one receives it)
Any idea?

Comment: If each process creates two processes ... that's it. Now you just owe me a little money for this advice. Just take a penny and put it in the first cell of a checkboard, then put twice that in the next cell, and then twice what is in the second cell in the third and so on until you fill the entire board, that should not be a lot, or is it?

Comment: But how do I simulate that scenario of having say 16 processes at the same time in memory sending messages to each other (8 processes sending, 8 processes receiving)?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand the question at all. If you manage to create a pair of them I don't understand how creating more processes is a problem!

Comment: @iharob it is because I am a C++ newbie. I want to have different msgbufers for every pair of processes. How do I make that happen.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the programming language, even with c++ this should be easy and elegant.

Comment: It seems like a matter of defining two processes, and then repeatedly forking them in messaging pairs.